# New to x86, think professor made a mistake

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm sorry to ask such a silly basic question, but it's the night before a quiz and I think I've recieved some faulty information about x86. I would appreciate some confirmation.

My professor asked us to "Move a word indirectly from memory to a register". 
She gave the following commands to do so:

```
mov bx, 01

mov [bx], ax
```

Now, to me, this looks like it's not moving a word from memory to a register but moving a word from a register (`ax`) to memory (`[bx]`). Is this correct or do I misunderstand?

Comment: the literal '01' has to be a source, it cannot be a destination, therefore bx is the destination for the first mov.  Assuming there is no typo then the next mov has to be interpreted the same way, first destination then source... so you are correct, the 2nd mov is a store to memory.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct. The second `mov` instruction should probably be `mov ax, [bx]`, which moves the word stored in the memory address in `bx` into the `ax` register.

Comment: mov     ax, WORD PTR [bx], was probably a typo on their part.

Comment: @Kibitz503 depending on the assembler, that is unnecessary. One can infer that since the target register is 16 bits, that it's a 16 bit memory access.

Answer (score 1):

You need to know which syntax you're using, there are two of them:

AT&T which is:

```
mov source, destination
```

And Intel, which is the other way around.

Your code looks like Intel syntax in which case the operands seem flipped.

Comment: AT&T syntax also uses `%` before each register. This is certainly Intel syntax.

Comment: Teaches sometimes leave them out (% before registers) of lectures to avoid focus on syntex (not that I agree with it). Thats what happend at my college atleast...

Comment: That professor should be punched in the face. Follow the damn syntax! How else do you know which syntax (and direction) is being used?!

Comment: Also, AT&T makes the operand size a part of the command mnemonic: `movb` for bytes, `movl` for DWORD-sized operands, etc. `mov` might not even be a valid command in AT&T style assembly (although in most cases size can be safely inferreed from operands).

Comment: The first example definitely suggests Intel syntax, and AT&T uses () for memory addresses.